# Mail sending but not receiving on Plesk server

Tags: email, sendmail, plesk

I am having some PLESK Mail receiving issues.

I just setup a dedicated server with 1and1. The server console is PLESK 12. I am using 1and1 nameserver which are pointed correctly from the domain registrars. I am able to send mail using webmail but not able to receive it.

When I do a mail server check it I get the following error:

```
Error connecting to mailserver: No route to host
```

If anyone is aware of some missing SMTP settings that need to be set up in the initial Plesk configuration it would be appreciated.

Comment: and your dns is setup correctly?